# Convert html file with inline mathml equations to a html with svg equations

Tags: html, svg, mathml

I have a big html file full of text, png figures and mathml equations.

I would like to convert all the mathml equations to svg images, since I will be reading this html in a device that does not support mathml, but can deal with svg and png's.

Is there any tool that can help with this task?

Comment: Use mathjax and don't convert at all.

Comment: Do you mean using mathjax to convert them to .svg's?

Comment: Sorry but this isn't what I am looking for, my device doesn't support js also.

Comment: Then there's two problems. a) we don't allow questions asking for tools and b) we've no details of what your device does and does not support so we can't advise any further.

Comment: @Socrates Were you able to find a solution to your problem? Thanks,